# Performance of UNet on low resolution images

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, cnn, computer-vision, research

I read the [U-Net paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) yesterday and it talked mostly about how it uses a small dataset (<100) of high-resolution images and performs efficiently.

I was wondering how it might perform on larger datasets (>1000) of low-resolution images.
One of it's properties is heavy use of Data Augmentation to compensate the size of training set as mentioned in the paper. Would that be as effective on low-res images?